# WPF - use new images from .exe file

Tags: c#, wpf, image

In my WPF application I added few images to my project in Visual Studio and changed their Build Action. And they work.
The problem is when I want to add new images to images folder. After that I launch my .exe file and application cannot see these new added images. 
How to resolve this?

```
private void ShowImage(Button button)
        {
            string buttonName = button.Name;
            string path = $@"Images/{buttonName}.png";

            Image image = new Image();
            image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(path, UriKind.Relative));
            button.Content = image;
        }
```

Comment: What is the Build action that you are setting and how are you loading your files can you share some code snippet.

Comment: Build Action: Content
Copy to Output Directory: Copy always

I added method that sets image as button content. 
Everything works fine when I add images to project before compiling. But I want to "manually" add images to folder without again compilation.

Comment: Are you copying the new image files to the actual output directory, e.g. `bin/Debug/Images/` or `bin/Release/Images/`? Provided that the image file name matches one of your Button names, that should work.

Comment: Yes. It can see new file ( I get the all files names and it is included ), but cannot display it.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question, I think the answer you are looking for is a component reference that'd look like so:

```
private void ShowImage(Button button)
    {
        string buttonName = button.Name;
        string path = "/MyProject;component/Images/{buttonName}.png";

        Image image = new Image();
        image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(path, UriKind.Relative));
        button.Content = image;
    }
```

Comment: Note that in code behind a [Pack URI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf) like this would need to be qualified with an appropriate prefix, either `pack://application:,,,` or `pack://siteoforigin:,,,`. It would also not work with `UriKind.Relative`.